# Does h5py read the whole file into memory?

Tags: python, h5py

Does h5py read the whole file into the memory?

If so, what if I have a very very big file?

If not, will it be quite slow if I take data from hard disk every time I want a single data? How can I make it faster?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does h5py read the whole file into the memory?

No, it does not. In particular, slicing (`dataset[50:100]`) allows you to load fractions of a dataset into memory. For details, see the [h5py docs](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html).

> If not, will it be quite slow if I take data from hard disk every time I want a single data?

In general, hdf5 is very fast. But reading from memory is obviously faster than reading from disk. It's your decision how much of a dataset is read into memory (`dataset[:]` loads the whole dataset).

> How can I make it faster?

If you care to optimize performance, you should read the [sections](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#chunked-storage) about *chunking* and *compression*. There's also a [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030249.do) that explains these things in detail (disclaimer: I'm not the author).

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to load entire HDF5 file (possibly nested) into memory, here is a simple utility function:

```
def load_entire_hdf5(dct):
    if isinstance(dct, h5py.Dataset):
        return dct[()]
    ret = {}
    for k, v in dct.items():
        ret[k] = load_entire_hdf5(v)
    return ret

with h5py.File("<filepath>", "r") as f:
    data = load_entire_hdf5(f)
```